Summernote Widget not displaying on inheriting from UpdateView
urls.py
path('post/<int:pk>/update/',  PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),

views.py:
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = PostForNewsFeed
    fields = ['post','title','content', 'tags','visibility']
    template_name = 'feed/create_post.html'
    widgets = {
             'content': SummernoteWidget(),
         }

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.user_name = self.request.user
            data.save()
            messages.success(self.request, f'Posted Successfully')
            return redirect('home2')

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.user_name:
            return True
        return False

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class PostForNewsFeed(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=POSTTYPE_CHOICES, default='Just a Mesage')
    #fullname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    content = models.TextField(default=None)

Summernote Widget wont render on PostupdateView
